# How to perform multiple condition in single mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i using following query to perform sum operation in two sub queries

```
select date,IFNULL(SUM(total_amount),0) as total from sales 
where date='".date("d/m/Y")."' 


select date,IFNULL(SUM(total_amount),0) as total from sales 
where str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= '".date("Y-m-01")."' and 
str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') <= '".date("Y-m-t")."'
```

How to perform in single query to make it simple. Please help me resolve my problem.

Comment: I see no benefit in getting the data from different time spans in one query.

Btw why do you save your dates as `varchar`s? It is much worse performance-wise than running two queries instead of one. For your use case `date` column type would be the best (and of course with an index created on that column).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join between the two select

```
select t1.date, t1.total, t2.total 
from (
    select date,IFNULL(SUM(total_amount),0) as total from sales 
    where date='".date("d/m/Y")."' 
) t1 
left join (
  select date,IFNULL(SUM(total_amount),0) as total from sales 
  where str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= '".date("Y-m-01")."' and 
  str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') <= '".date("Y-m-t")."'
) y2 on t1.date = t2.date
```